# How to select latest item in lazy loaded dropdown list using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm using VueJS and Cypress to test e2e. I also use Vuetify's dropdown:

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="selecter">
  <v-select
    v-model="courseSelection.value"
    :items="courseOptions"
    :error-messages="courseSelection.errors"
    :disabled="courseSelection.disabled"
    label="select"
    required
    outlined
    dense
  />
</div>
```

The `courseOptions` contains a lot of options with lazy-loading, meaning it loads if you scroll down. I'm trying to get latest item on that list, but I can't seem to figure a way to scroll down and so it could be loaded. What I tried:

```
cy.get('#selecter').click(); 
cy.get(".v-menu__content.theme--light.v-menu__content--fixed").eq(0).scrollIntoView();
cy.get('div[role="listbox"]').find('div[role="option"]').eq(-1).click();
```

But it selects only the latest loaded item and not the actual latest item. How it can be done?